# Whats wrong with my program?

Tags: stm32, arm, stm32f10x

I am trying to turn on LED on PC8 STM32VL Discovery board(Micro: STM32F100RB). I am using linker script provided by st.com (stm32_flash.ld):

```
/*
*****************************************************************************
**
**  File        : stm32_flash.ld
**
**  Abstract    : Linker script for STM32F100VB Device with
**                128KByte FLASH, 8KByte RAM
**
**                Set heap size, stack size and stack location according
**                to application requirements.
**
**                Set memory bank area and size if external memory is used.
**
**  Target      : STMicroelectronics STM32
**
**  Environment : Atollic TrueSTUDIO(R)
**
**  Distribution: The file is distributed “as is,” without any warranty
**                of any kind.
**
**  (c)Copyright Atollic AB.
**  You may use this file as-is or modify it according to the needs of your
**  project. Distribution of this file (unmodified or modified) is not
**  permitted. Atollic AB permit registered Atollic TrueSTUDIO(R) users the
**  rights to distribute the assembled, compiled & linked contents of this
**  file as part of an application binary file, provided that it is built
**  using the Atollic TrueSTUDIO(R) toolchain.
**
*****************************************************************************
*/

/* Entry Point */
ENTRY(Reset_Handler)

/* Highest address of the user mode stack */
_estack = 0x20002000;    /* end of 8K RAM */

/* Generate a link error if heap and stack don't fit into RAM */
_Min_Heap_Size = 0;      /* required amount of heap  */
_Min_Stack_Size = 0x100; /* required amount of stack */

/* Specify the memory areas */
MEMORY
{
  FLASH (rx)      : ORIGIN = 0x08000000, LENGTH = 128K
  RAM (xrw)       : ORIGIN = 0x20000000, LENGTH = 8K
  MEMORY_B1 (rx)  : ORIGIN = 0x60000000, LENGTH = 0K
}

/* Define output sections */
SECTIONS
{
  /* The startup code goes first into FLASH */
  .isr_vector :
  {
    . = ALIGN(4);
    KEEP(*(.isr_vector)) /* Startup code */
    . = ALIGN(4);
  } >FLASH

  /* The program code and other data goes into FLASH */
  .text :
  {
    . = ALIGN(4);
    *(.text)           /* .text sections (code) */
    *(.text*)          /* .text* sections (code) */
    *(.rodata)         /* .rodata sections (constants, strings, etc.) */
    *(.rodata*)        /* .rodata* sections (constants, strings, etc.) */
    *(.glue_7)         /* glue arm to thumb code */
    *(.glue_7t)        /* glue thumb to arm code */

    KEEP (*(.init))
    KEEP (*(.fini))

    . = ALIGN(4);
    _etext = .;        /* define a global symbols at end of code */
  } >FLASH


   .ARM.extab   : { *(.ARM.extab* .gnu.linkonce.armextab.*) } >FLASH
    .ARM : {
    __exidx_start = .;
      *(.ARM.exidx*)
      __exidx_end = .;
    } >FLASH

  .ARM.attributes : { *(.ARM.attributes) } > FLASH

  .preinit_array     :
  {
    PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__preinit_array_start = .);
    KEEP (*(.preinit_array*))
    PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__preinit_array_end = .);
  } >FLASH
  .init_array :
  {
    PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__init_array_start = .);
    KEEP (*(SORT(.init_array.*)))
    KEEP (*(.init_array*))
    PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__init_array_end = .);
  } >FLASH
  .fini_array :
  {
    PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__fini_array_start = .);
    KEEP (*(.fini_array*))
    KEEP (*(SORT(.fini_array.*)))
    PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__fini_array_end = .);
  } >FLASH

  /* used by the startup to initialize data */
  _sidata = .;

  /* Initialized data sections goes into RAM, load LMA copy after code */
  .data : AT ( _sidata )
  {
    . = ALIGN(4);
    _sdata = .;        /* create a global symbol at data start */
    *(.data)           /* .data sections */
    *(.data*)          /* .data* sections */

    . = ALIGN(4);
    _edata = .;        /* define a global symbol at data end */
  } >RAM

  /* Uninitialized data section */
  . = ALIGN(4);
  .bss :
  {
    /* This is used by the startup in order to initialize the .bss secion */
    _sbss = .;         /* define a global symbol at bss start */
    __bss_start__ = _sbss;
    *(.bss)
    *(.bss*)
    *(COMMON)

    . = ALIGN(4);
    _ebss = .;         /* define a global symbol at bss end */
    __bss_end__ = _ebss;
  } >RAM

  PROVIDE ( end = _ebss );
  PROVIDE ( _end = _ebss );

  /* User_heap_stack section, used to check that there is enough RAM left */
  ._user_heap_stack :
  {
    . = ALIGN(4);
    . = . + _Min_Heap_Size;
    . = . + _Min_Stack_Size;
    . = ALIGN(4);
  } >RAM

  /* MEMORY_bank1 section, code must be located here explicitly            */
  /* Example: extern int foo(void) __attribute__ ((section (".mb1text"))); */
  .memory_b1_text :
  {
    *(.mb1text)        /* .mb1text sections (code) */
    *(.mb1text*)       /* .mb1text* sections (code)  */
    *(.mb1rodata)      /* read-only data (constants) */
    *(.mb1rodata*)
  } >MEMORY_B1

  /* Remove information from the standard libraries */
  /DISCARD/ :
  {
    libc.a ( * )
    libm.a ( * )
    libgcc.a ( * )
  }
}
```

and also startup file from st.com(startup_stm32f10x_md_vl.s):

```
/**
  ******************************************************************************
  * @file      startup_stm32f10x_md_vl.s
  * @author    MCD Application Team
  * @version   V3.5.0
  * @date      11-March-2011
  * @brief     STM32F10x Medium Density Value Line Devices vector table for RIDE7
  *            toolchain.
  *            This module performs:
  *                - Set the initial SP
  *                - Set the initial PC == Reset_Handler,
  *                - Set the vector table entries with the exceptions ISR address
  *                - Configure the clock system                 
  *                - Branches to main in the C library (which eventually
  *                  calls main()).
  *            After Reset the Cortex-M3 processor is in Thread mode,
  *            priority is Privileged, and the Stack is set to Main.
  ******************************************************************************
 */

  .syntax unified
  .cpu cortex-m3
  .fpu softvfp
  .thumb

.global  g_pfnVectors
.global  Default_Handler

/* start address for the initialization values of the .data section. 
defined in linker script */
.word  _sidata
/* start address for the .data section. defined in linker script */  
.word  _sdata
/* end address for the .data section. defined in linker script */
.word  _edata
/* start address for the .bss section. defined in linker script */
.word  _sbss
/* end address for the .bss section. defined in linker script */
.word  _ebss

.equ  BootRAM, 0xF108F85F
/**
 * @brief  This is the code that gets called when the processor first
 *          starts execution following a reset event. Only the absolutely
 *          necessary set is performed, after which the application
 *          supplied main() routine is called. 
 * @param  None
 * @retval None
*/
_estack = 0x20002000;

  .section  .text.Reset_Handler
  .weak  Reset_Handler
  .type  Reset_Handler, %function
Reset_Handler:  

/* Copy the data segment initializers from flash to SRAM */  
  movs  r1, #0
  b     LoopCopyDataInit

CopyDataInit:
  ldr   r3, =_sidata
  ldr   r3, [r3, r1]
  str   r3, [r0, r1]
  adds  r1, r1, #4

LoopCopyDataInit:
  ldr   r0, =_sdata
  ldr   r3, =_edata
  adds  r2, r0, r1
  cmp   r2, r3
  bcc   CopyDataInit
  ldr   r2, =_sbss
  b     LoopFillZerobss
/* Zero fill the bss segment. */  
FillZerobss:
  movs  r3, #0
  str   r3, [r2], #4

LoopFillZerobss:
  ldr   r3, = _ebss
  cmp   r2, r3
  bcc   FillZerobss
/* Call the clock system intitialization function.*/
  bl  SystemInit   
/* Call the application's entry point.*/
  bl    main
  bx    lr    
.size   Reset_Handler, .-Reset_Handler

/**
 * @brief  This is the code that gets called when the processor receives an 
 *         unexpected interrupt. This simply enters an infinite loop, preserving
 *         the system state for examination by a debugger.
 * @param  None     
 * @retval None       
*/
  .section  .text.Default_Handler,"ax",%progbits
Default_Handler:
Infinite_Loop:
  b  Infinite_Loop
  .size  Default_Handler, .-Default_Handler
/******************************************************************************
*
* The minimal vector table for a Cortex M3. Note that the proper constructs
* must be placed on this to ensure that it ends up at physical address
* 0x0000.0000.
* 
******************************************************************************/    
  .section  .isr_vector,"a",%progbits
  .type  g_pfnVectors, %object
  .size  g_pfnVectors, .-g_pfnVectors

g_pfnVectors:
  .word  _estack
  .word  Reset_Handler
  .word  NMI_Handler
  .word  HardFault_Handler
  .word  MemManage_Handler
  .word  BusFault_Handler
  .word  UsageFault_Handler
  .word  0
  .word  0
  .word  0
  .word  0
  .word  SVC_Handler
  .word  DebugMon_Handler
  .word  0
  .word  PendSV_Handler
  .word  SysTick_Handler
  .word  WWDG_IRQHandler
  .word  PVD_IRQHandler
  .word  TAMPER_IRQHandler
  .word  RTC_IRQHandler
  .word  FLASH_IRQHandler
  .word  RCC_IRQHandler
  .word  EXTI0_IRQHandler
  .word  EXTI1_IRQHandler
  .word  EXTI2_IRQHandler
  .word  EXTI3_IRQHandler
  .word  EXTI4_IRQHandler
  .word  DMA1_Channel1_IRQHandler
  .word  DMA1_Channel2_IRQHandler
  .word  DMA1_Channel3_IRQHandler
  .word  DMA1_Channel4_IRQHandler
  .word  DMA1_Channel5_IRQHandler
  .word  DMA1_Channel6_IRQHandler
  .word  DMA1_Channel7_IRQHandler
  .word  ADC1_IRQHandler
  .word  0
  .word  0
  .word  0
  .word  0
  .word  EXTI9_5_IRQHandler
  .word  TIM1_BRK_TIM15_IRQHandler
  .word  TIM1_UP_TIM16_IRQHandler
  .word  TIM1_TRG_COM_TIM17_IRQHandler
  .word  TIM1_CC_IRQHandler
  .word  TIM2_IRQHandler
  .word  TIM3_IRQHandler
  .word  TIM4_IRQHandler
  .word  I2C1_EV_IRQHandler
  .word  I2C1_ER_IRQHandler
  .word  I2C2_EV_IRQHandler
  .word  I2C2_ER_IRQHandler
  .word  SPI1_IRQHandler
  .word  SPI2_IRQHandler
  .word  USART1_IRQHandler
  .word  USART2_IRQHandler
  .word  USART3_IRQHandler
  .word  EXTI15_10_IRQHandler
  .word  RTCAlarm_IRQHandler
  .word  CEC_IRQHandler  
  .word  0
  .word  0
  .word  0
  .word  0
  .word  0
  .word  0
  .word  0
  .word  0  
  .word  0
  .word  0
  .word  0
  .word  TIM6_DAC_IRQHandler
  .word  TIM7_IRQHandler  
  .word  0
  .word  0
  .word  0
  .word  0
  .word  0
  .word  0
  .word  0
  .word  0
  .word  0
  .word  0
  .word  0
  .word  0
  .word  0
  .word  0
  .word  0
  .word  0
  .word  0
  .word  0
  .word  0
  .word  0
  .word  0
  .word  0
  .word  0
  .word  0
  .word  0
  .word  0
  .word  0
  .word  0
  .word  0
  .word  0
  .word  0
  .word  0
  .word  0
  .word  0
  .word  0
  .word  0
  .word  0
  .word  0
  .word  0
  .word  0
  .word  0
  .word  0
  .word  0
  .word  BootRAM          /* @0x01CC. This is for boot in RAM mode for 
                            STM32F10x Medium Value Line Density devices. */

/*******************************************************************************
* Provide weak aliases for each Exception handler to the Default_Handler. 
* As they are weak aliases, any function with the same name will override 
* this definition.
*******************************************************************************/

  .weak  NMI_Handler
  .thumb_set NMI_Handler,Default_Handler

  .weak  HardFault_Handler
  .thumb_set HardFault_Handler,Default_Handler

  .weak  MemManage_Handler
  .thumb_set MemManage_Handler,Default_Handler

  .weak  BusFault_Handler
  .thumb_set BusFault_Handler,Default_Handler

  .weak  UsageFault_Handler
  .thumb_set UsageFault_Handler,Default_Handler

  .weak  SVC_Handler
  .thumb_set SVC_Handler,Default_Handler

  .weak  DebugMon_Handler
  .thumb_set DebugMon_Handler,Default_Handler

  .weak  PendSV_Handler
  .thumb_set PendSV_Handler,Default_Handler

  .weak  SysTick_Handler
  .thumb_set SysTick_Handler,Default_Handler

  .weak  WWDG_IRQHandler
  .thumb_set WWDG_IRQHandler,Default_Handler

  .weak  PVD_IRQHandler
  .thumb_set PVD_IRQHandler,Default_Handler

  .weak  TAMPER_IRQHandler
  .thumb_set TAMPER_IRQHandler,Default_Handler

  .weak  RTC_IRQHandler
  .thumb_set RTC_IRQHandler,Default_Handler

  .weak  FLASH_IRQHandler
  .thumb_set FLASH_IRQHandler,Default_Handler

  .weak  RCC_IRQHandler
  .thumb_set RCC_IRQHandler,Default_Handler

  .weak  EXTI0_IRQHandler
  .thumb_set EXTI0_IRQHandler,Default_Handler

  .weak  EXTI1_IRQHandler
  .thumb_set EXTI1_IRQHandler,Default_Handler

  .weak  EXTI2_IRQHandler
  .thumb_set EXTI2_IRQHandler,Default_Handler

  .weak  EXTI3_IRQHandler
  .thumb_set EXTI3_IRQHandler,Default_Handler

  .weak  EXTI4_IRQHandler
  .thumb_set EXTI4_IRQHandler,Default_Handler

  .weak  DMA1_Channel1_IRQHandler
  .thumb_set DMA1_Channel1_IRQHandler,Default_Handler

  .weak  DMA1_Channel2_IRQHandler
  .thumb_set DMA1_Channel2_IRQHandler,Default_Handler

  .weak  DMA1_Channel3_IRQHandler
  .thumb_set DMA1_Channel3_IRQHandler,Default_Handler

  .weak  DMA1_Channel4_IRQHandler
  .thumb_set DMA1_Channel4_IRQHandler,Default_Handler

  .weak  DMA1_Channel5_IRQHandler
  .thumb_set DMA1_Channel5_IRQHandler,Default_Handler

  .weak  DMA1_Channel6_IRQHandler
  .thumb_set DMA1_Channel6_IRQHandler,Default_Handler

  .weak  DMA1_Channel7_IRQHandler
  .thumb_set DMA1_Channel7_IRQHandler,Default_Handler

  .weak  ADC1_IRQHandler
  .thumb_set ADC1_IRQHandler,Default_Handler

  .weak  EXTI9_5_IRQHandler
  .thumb_set EXTI9_5_IRQHandler,Default_Handler

  .weak  TIM1_BRK_TIM15_IRQHandler
  .thumb_set TIM1_BRK_TIM15_IRQHandler,Default_Handler

  .weak  TIM1_UP_TIM16_IRQHandler
  .thumb_set TIM1_UP_TIM16_IRQHandler,Default_Handler

  .weak  TIM1_TRG_COM_TIM17_IRQHandler
  .thumb_set TIM1_TRG_COM_TIM17_IRQHandler,Default_Handler

  .weak  TIM1_CC_IRQHandler
  .thumb_set TIM1_CC_IRQHandler,Default_Handler

  .weak  TIM2_IRQHandler
  .thumb_set TIM2_IRQHandler,Default_Handler

  .weak  TIM3_IRQHandler
  .thumb_set TIM3_IRQHandler,Default_Handler

  .weak  TIM4_IRQHandler
  .thumb_set TIM4_IRQHandler,Default_Handler

  .weak  I2C1_EV_IRQHandler
  .thumb_set I2C1_EV_IRQHandler,Default_Handler

  .weak  I2C1_ER_IRQHandler
  .thumb_set I2C1_ER_IRQHandler,Default_Handler

  .weak  I2C2_EV_IRQHandler
  .thumb_set I2C2_EV_IRQHandler,Default_Handler

  .weak  I2C2_ER_IRQHandler
  .thumb_set I2C2_ER_IRQHandler,Default_Handler

  .weak  SPI1_IRQHandler
  .thumb_set SPI1_IRQHandler,Default_Handler

  .weak  SPI2_IRQHandler
  .thumb_set SPI2_IRQHandler,Default_Handler

  .weak  USART1_IRQHandler
  .thumb_set USART1_IRQHandler,Default_Handler

  .weak  USART2_IRQHandler
  .thumb_set USART2_IRQHandler,Default_Handler

  .weak  USART3_IRQHandler
  .thumb_set USART3_IRQHandler,Default_Handler

  .weak  EXTI15_10_IRQHandler
  .thumb_set EXTI15_10_IRQHandler,Default_Handler

  .weak  RTCAlarm_IRQHandler
  .thumb_set RTCAlarm_IRQHandler,Default_Handler

  .weak  CEC_IRQHandler
  .thumb_set CEC_IRQHandler,Default_Handler

  .weak  TIM6_DAC_IRQHandler
  .thumb_set TIM6_DAC_IRQHandler,Default_Handler

  .weak  TIM7_IRQHandler
  .thumb_set TIM7_IRQHandler,Default_Handler  

/******************* (C) COPYRIGHT 2011 STMicroelectronics *****END OF FILE****/
```

And this is system_stm32f10x_md_vl.c file written by me(systeminit()):

```
#include "stm32f10x.h"

void SystemInit(void)
{
    /* Enable HSI-RC */
    RCC->CR |= (uint32_t) 0x1;

    /* Select HSI as System Clock */
    RCC->CFGR &= (uint32_t) 0xfffffffffc;

    /* Set AHPR prescalar as 1 */
    RCC->CFGR &= (uint32_t)0xffffffff0f;

    /* Set APB2 prescalar to 1 */
    RCC->CFGR &= (uint32_t)0xffffffc7ff;

}
```

and this is "main.c"

```
#include "stm32f10x.h"

int main(void)
{
    /* Enable GPIOC from APB2 */
    RCC->APB2ENR |= (uint32_t)0x20;



    /* Set PC8 Mode to Output mode speed 50Mhz */
    GPIOC->CRH |= (uint32_t)0x3;

    /* Set PC8 Config to Output push-pull */
    GPIOC->CRH &= (uint32_t) 0xfffffffff3;

    /* Set Pin8 On portC to 1 */
    GPIOC->BSRR |= (uint32_t) 0x100;

    while (1)
    {
    }
}
```

Why my LED on PC8 Does not turn on???
what is wrong??

Comment: Kudos for actually including the linker and startup code as part of your question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your code is full of 'magic' numbers which are prone to silly errors. You are attempting to enable Port C with this:-

```
 /* Enable GPIOC from APB2 */
 RCC->APB2ENR |= (uint32_t)0x20;
```

But `stm32f10x.h` has this:-

```
#define  RCC_APB2ENR_IOPCEN ((uint32_t)0x00000010) /* I/O port C clock enable */
```

Wherever possible you should use symbolic names rather than plain numbers. They help make the code 'self-documenting', reduce the chances of errors like this, and save time and effort when they need to be modified (only have to change the number in one place rather than everywhere you used it). If you include the standard header file then you don't have to worry about whether you got the numbers right.